# settinng proxy to the bamboo remote agent

Tags: bamboo

We have installed bamboo remote agent in one our servers using atlassian documentation. We have approved that agent it is connecting well with bamboo master server and we were able to run builds. The issue that we are facing is proxy settings. Is there a way where we can set a proxy inside remote agent that connects to external servers for getting libraries to build succesfully. What we had to do now is configure the proxy manually to the gradle tasks in builds. This is not the way to do it. Cause 100 builds might come in future where we need proxy settings. we cannot configure proxy manually to all those builds, you might suggest we set up global variable solution in builds, we are not looking for that.

Can you suggest as to how to get proxy for http and https through bamboo remote agent. (https_proxy=http://1*.**.**.19:80,http_proxy=http://1*.**.**.19:80)

What we have tried so far,

We have added the proxy settings for http and https to the bamboo startup scrip in bin directory. 
-- It did not work.

We have added it to the wrapper.conf as additional java arguemnt and additional app parameters
we have tried both ways. 
---It did not work either, what happened was when we restarted bamboo remote agent after that setup, bamboo remote agent was trying to connect to master agent through that proxy ip. that is causing the bamboo remote agent to go down, is there any way where we can configure a proxy and tell bamboo remote agent to not use this proxy to connect to master agent. this could be a possible solution.

There is a file name called bamboo-remote-cfg.xml, there is not enough documentation on it as to how to add parameters if we want to. I was wondering if we could add proxy ip there. Please suggest.

Can we configure proxy as a capability in bamboo agent. Would it work?

we have also configured proxy settings using the users .bash_profile, it does not work, apparantly bamboo before starting builds blows off all the env variables set on server.

Please suggest on above options. and let us know if you have a solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

we set proxy in wrapper.conf file using set.default.HTTPS_PROXY and set.default.HTTP_PROXY arguments. That fixed it.

If this did not work set up proxy in gradle in the server itself. Or maven if you are using it. Although its a work around this helps as well.